# EXCEL: Formula to Determine whether a date is “within Business Hours” or “Outside Business Hours” or "Weekend" in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to create a formula(s) for SLA report to show whether an agent acknowledged the assignment within the SLA or not.

I found a formula in one of the other posts to show office hours are from

```
Mon-Fri ONLY from 8-5:30pm
```

> I want to exclude evening, weekends, and holidays.

Can it say "after hours" or "weekend" or "holiday" instead of using `IN` or `OUT`?

How to modify the formula to work? i tried other formats as well but it was the length of a novel and it didn't work.

```
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A2)>1,MOD(A2,1)*24>=8,MOD(A2,1)*24<=IF(WEEKDAY(A2)=7,14,20)
),"In","Out")
```

The section [7,14,20] was replaced with 17:30 (for 5:30pm)

```
A2=start time (DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM)
B2=end time
```

Comment: what about the workday() function?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mike. How would that formula work?

Comment: It was something that you may not have found, for you to consider...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you first place your data and criteria into tables, which will make organization, referencing and updating easier.  To do this quickly, highlight your range and then Ctrl + T.  That will open a new ribbon tab for Table Design, and you can give the table a name.  I prefer to start all of my table names with t_.  In the example below, there are three tables:

1) t_BusinessHours
2) t_Holidays
3) t_Data_AcknowledgmentTimes

[image]

[image]

To achieve your desired results, you will need a couple of nested formulas. I've broken them down so you can see what each part does.  Then combined them for the one result column.  As you can see, when your data is in tables, you can easily reference the parts you need using the table name and column headers instead of column letters/row numbers.

[image]

After opening time?

```
=IF(TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),0)>=MIN(t_BusinessHours[Time]),"After Open","Before Open")
```

Before closing time?

```
=IF(TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),0)<MAX(t_BusinessHours[Time]),"Before Close","After Close")
```

Weekend?

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(WEEKDAY(A2,2))>5,"Weekend","Weekday")
```

Holiday?

```
=IF(COUNTIF(t_Holidays,EDATE(A2,0))>0,"Holiday","Not Holiday")
```

Put it together (Example, don't use this one - use the one below)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(t_Holidays,EDATE(A2,0))>0,"Holiday",
IF(ISNUMBER(WEEKDAY(A2,2))>5,"Weekend",
IF(AND(TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),0)<MIN(t_BusinessHours[Time]),
TIME(HOUR(A2),MINUTE(A2),0)>=MAX(t_BusinessHours[Time])),
"After Hours","During Business Hours")))
```

Result (A2 in the formula above is replaced with the table reference)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(t_Holidays,EDATE([@[Start Time]],0))>0,"Holiday",
IF(ISNUMBER(WEEKDAY([@[Start Time]],2))>5,"Weekend",
IF(AND(TIME(HOUR([@[Start Time]]),MINUTE([@[Start Time]]),0)<MIN(t_BusinessHours[Time]),
TIME(HOUR([@[Start Time]]),MINUTE([@[Start Time]]),0)>=MAX(t_BusinessHours[Time])),"After Hours","During Business Hours")))
```

Comment: Jenn, thank you for the mini lesson with graphics. So, So helpful for someone who isn't an Excel expert.  Is it possible to integrate another formula in there to auto-update the total time count, excluding the time (after hours, weekends, holidays) that we just pinpointed? or is that a separate formula?

Comment: You are very welcome.  Yes, this is possible.  Are you wanting to add a separate column for the elapsed time?